# Match string with normal characters with special characters in python

Tags: python, regex, special-characters, information-retrieval

I'm trying to find a way to match user search queries with a database records in a search engine, using python, but I'm having trouble when the search query includes special characters such as vowels with accent.

Eg: search query = 'cafe'. Database record = 'café'

I'm using the stem of words to the query with the database records.

Which would be the most straight forward way of matching the query including a special character 'café' with the string that doesn't contain this special character 'cafe' and viceversa?

**UPDATE**

All the information I need is already cached so the approach of creating a new column in the db is not so appealing. I'm looking for a solution more python based.

Comment: what regex pattern are you using ?

Comment: no regex pattern yet @Alok, just thought I could use it but might match too many records.

Comment: What your actual question or problem ?

Comment: if you are searching for exact word matches only, and your DB records contain single words only, you could have a second column in the DB, set to the 'de-accented' version of the word. Then you can just run your DB query against that. It would double your DB size tho.

Comment: @DiegoAgher @TomDalton: That what I thought about. But won't it be better if there is a second column `tags` having `de-accented` or `accented` words, so that it could match in both cases.

Comment: @noob not clear what you mean by the column having x *or* y - a column can only contain one thing, right?

Comment: Not entirely. A column can contain words separated by `,`. Using programming the word in the search query can look for `tags` and return the result.

Comment: @noob But you wouldn't be able to index the column, and your queries would then have to do a full-row scan plus an expensive 'if search_term in table.tags' clause in the query. This would be a terrible performance hit for a non-trivial DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this issue with the following code:

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', "café").encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

which returned

```
cafe
```

This method also corrects characters such as: ü,ö,á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, ī

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are few ways of doing that.

My guess is that simplest and easiest( but **not best**) way to do it for you by creating special map with characters witch could replace each other and than create your query by using that map:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_MAP = {
    'e': u'[eé]',
}

def get_query(string):
    pattern_value = u''
    for s in string:
        pattern_value += s if s not in SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_MAP else SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_MAP[s]
    query = u"SELECT * FROM table WHERE record LIKE '%{}%'".format(pattern_value)
    return query


print get_query(u'ewqeé')
# SELECT * FROM table WHERE record LIKE '%[eé]wq[eé]é%'

# Code to query database ....
```

So you could extend your map with more cases like `'a': 'u[aà]'` etc.

Another option is to create separate column in database and fill that column with replacing special characters to usual by using quite similar structure of data like `SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_MAP` above, designed to make replacement of characters easier for you, but in that case you have to perform same replacement before passing search term into `LIKE` query.

[SQL Wildcards](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) is use full thing information for creating string you are going to match while executing `SELECT` query with `LIKE` operator.